# How to extract nightly features used in a crate?

Tags: rust, compiler-construction

I want to extract all nightly features used by a crate for some research purposes.

Just to be clear, "nightly features" means codes like `#![feature(...)]"`, but not crate provided optional features.

I tried using regex, and it works, but not accurate enough. cfg defined features may not be detected: `#![cfg_attr(target_os = "macos", feature(...))]`.

So I turn to rustc compiler, I wish to modify some source code and print out what features crate uses. Now I'm still trying to find out how rustc deals with nightly features.

I hope someone can give me some tips and help about the process of rustc dealing with nightly features. I'm almost lost in codes.

Comment: Perhaps you could compile with a stable build and parse the compiler errors?

Comment: @PeterHall `--message-format=json` is likely to be helpful with that, but I'm not sure this is the best way.

Comment: Modifying the rust compiler is a hassle. Are you sure you want to do that? Also, do you want to identify _active_ features (after cfg expansion) or all features?

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks, I would give it a try. But I think it may not be working. We are actually doing some research on rust ecosystem, which means, some crates may be old and cannot be compiled. In such cases, compiler errors may not include feature errors.

Comment: @Chayim Friedman Thanks. I do think modifying the compiler is a great disaster... But I just don't know any better way...

I want to identify active features, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access to enabled features is done via [`rustc_session::Session::features`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_session/struct.Session.html#structfield.features). You can add code after [they are set in `rustc_interface`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2643b16468fda787470340890212591d8bc832b7/compiler/rustc_interface/src/passes.rs#L186), or look at [how they're computed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8d1fa7105b2ad3154f63d8f0641fd7da87e20e8f/compiler/rustc_expand/src/config.rs#L36-L236).

If you are at a later stage, you probably have access to the `Session` of the compiled crate. For example, [`TyCtxt` has a `sess()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_middle/ty/context/struct.TyCtxt.html#method.sess) (but also a [`features()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_middle/ty/context/struct.TyCtxt.html#method.features) method for direct access using the query system), and [`InferCtxt` has a `tcx` member to access the `TyCtxt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_infer/infer/struct.InferCtxt.html#structfield.tcx).