# How cfg are dealt with in rustc?

Tags: rust, compiler-construction

This is a further question on [How to extract nightly features used in a crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73288554/how-to-extract-nightly-features-used-in-a-crate).

I also want to know where and how `#![cfg_attr(target_os = "macos", feature(...))]` is turned into `#![feature(...)`.

Could someone give me some tips about the process of rustc dealing with cfg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`rustc_expand`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_expand/index.html) crate is responsible for expanding macros. It [special cases](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4b91a6ea7258a947e59c6522cd5898e7c0a6a88f/compiler/rustc_expand/src/expand.rs#L1660-L1669) `#[cfg]` and `#[cfg_attr]` when parsing attribute macros such that they aren't treated like normal macros.

- `rustc_expand` calls [`rustc_parse::parse_cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.63.0/nightly-rustc/rustc_parse/fn.parse_cfg_attr.html) to parse the attribute.
- With the parsed macro, `rustc_expand` calls [`rustc_attr::cfg_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.63.0/nightly-rustc/rustc_attr/fn.cfg_matches.html) to evaluate if the condition is met.
- `rustc_expand` then either includes or doesn't include the attribute passed as an argument.